# How can I count the amount of items per user?

Tags: sql

What I need to do is to Count the Times a User has received the treatment 'Oxygen'. I'm trying to do like below but I'm getting all of the entries from Treatment_Victim per user. Any help is well appreciated. Should I be using something else?

| ID_Victim | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Alex |

| ID_Treatment | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Oxygen |
| 2 | Transfussion |

| ID_Treatment_Victim | ID_Victim | ID_Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

```
SELECT v.Name, count(tv.ID_Treatment_Victim) AS Times
FROM Victim v, Treatment t, Treatment_Victim tv
WHERE v.ID_Victim = tv.ID_Victim
AND tv.ID_Treatment = (SELECT ID_Treatment
    FROM Treatment
    WHERE Treatment.Nombre = 'Oxigen')
GROUP BY v.ID_Victim
ORDER BY Times DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT v.Name, COUNT(*) AS Times
FROM Treatment_Victim tv JOIN
     Victim v
     ON v.ID_Victim = tv.ID_Victim JOIN
     Treatment t
     ON v.ID_Treatment = tv.ID_Treatment
WHERE t.Nombre = 'Oxigen'
GROUP BY v.ID_Victim, v.Name
ORDER BY Times DESC
LIMIT 5;
```